# Can I change value of constant in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need this hack for legacy .NET dll which cannot be recompiled. Some hack e.g. using reflection, etc.

Comment: Oh dear, imagine the chaos that will follow of making a constant non-constant. It might even bring Elvis back.

Comment: do you need the value to be changed for use internally within the dll or only where it is used by references outside the dll?

Comment: Yes, I can imagine. That's why I am talking about hack.

Comment: I hope you did not take offence by my joke there; I really should have included a smiley. It's a good question, with lots of interesting implications to think about (so I upvoted it).

Comment: This is certainly possible as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77694339/2638227).

Answer (score 17):

if the assembly is not signed then you might be able to either dissassemble and modify the IL and recompile, or disassemble to source and modify and recompile.  I'll find the appropriate links....

To disassemble to source you can use [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) (warning- no longer free) with [Dennis Bauers plugin](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) or you can use [reflexil](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/reflexil.aspx) which is another plugin for reflector which comes with a complete VB/C# editor and intellisense allowing code injection directly from Reflector.

to disassemble to IL you can use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) disassembler  or the [MSILDissasembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

As others have pointed out though you want to carefully consider the implications of doing this.  It may have more knock-ons that you realise.

The other thing that is very important is that if the constant is used by other dlls which reference the dll you are recompiling compiling, those dlls **WILL NOT SEE THE NEW VALUE FOR THE CONSTANT WITHOUT ALSO BEING RECOMPILED**.

This is because when something is defined as a constant, the 'constant' value is baked into the referencing dll as an optimisation (so it doesn't need to be looked up in the referenced dll every time it is used) **AT BUILD TIME** so changes to the 'constant' value are never actually seen in any libraries that reference the 'constant'.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523241/net-c-string-reference-in-code-behind-not-loading-updated-value) and answers for some more details.

Comment: JustDecompile is free and supports reflexil.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Stecya's answer:
The value of the const variable will be inserted anywhere it is used. This means that all assemblies referencing your legacy assembly and using that constant need to be recompiled also to reflect the updated value of the const variable. That's BTW the reason why it is a good idea to always expose constant values through normal properties in public interfaces.

Comment: This is one of those answers I wish I could upvote twice; one vote for pointing out the need to recompile consuming code, and one for "don't expose constants directly".

Comment: yeah +1 for the always expose the constants through a property.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change const because it is compile-time calculated. Only way is to change that const filed is to modify that legacy assembly

Answer (score 3):

Reflections won't work because this value is hard-coded into the byte code of the application in a way that reflections wont be able to modify.

If it is not code signed, use a hex editor or ILDasm to modify the value of the constant.

If it is code signed, you have no way to solve this without foregoing code signing.

If you are editing a compiled assembly, be careful.  There may be legal reasons you can't do that either.

Answer (score 1):

const values are replaced as literals during compile time, so highly unlikely you would be able to change it without recompiling

Answer (score -2):

Changing a constant value is not possible with conventional methods but **is possible with pointers**.

Mark the method as `unsafe`, use the `fixed` keyword to pin the string in memory and get a pointer to the character data:

```cs
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get the string from an external .NET DLL or for simplicity
    // from a local variable and change it.
    // string text = ClassLibrary.Class1.ConstValue;
    string text = "xyz";
    fixed (char* ptrText = text)
    {
        // Print initial state
        Console.WriteLine($"Text: {text}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The address of text is: {(IntPtr)ptrText}");

        // Modify the string
        char* p = ptrText;
        for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            *p = '?';
            p++;
        }

        // Print final state
        Console.WriteLine($"Text: {text}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The address of text is: {(IntPtr)ptrText}");
    }
}
```

The output will be something like

```
Text: xyz
The address of text is: 2017642344732
Text: ???
The address of text is: 2017642344732
```

Note that the memory addresses are the same before and after the modification.
Don't forget to check the *Unsafe code* checkbox in the *Project Properties > Build > General* section.