# Changing Variable Type on RunTime

Tags: c#, variables, reflection, types

Today i had a challenge with my College and i gaved up ,no idea how to achieve it .
Is there a way to declare a String ,as Constant and on Load Event maybe using Reflection to change String to non-Constant assign a value from XML ,than Change it to Constant again .

And all of the Code which does that (Constant to Non-Constant),should be Stored in a String ,and on Load before Type Change ,it should be Decrypted and Injected into the Application .

**example:**

```
private const String RegNumber = "";
//Change RegNumber to Writable String
//Change RegNumber value
//Than Change RegNumber back to const again
```

PS : Please sorry but i have no idea where to start ,and show here some code .

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.  Please reword it.

Comment: @Jason please read again ,and tell me what don't you understand !

Comment: You cannot change a constant value using reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare it as `const` but you *can* declare it as `static readonly`:

```
private static readonly string Foo = ReadValueFromAssembly();

static string ReadValueFromAssembly()
{
    // Perform your logic and return the string here
}
```

Would that do everything you need? It's not really clear what you mean about the "code which does that [...] should be decrypted and injected into the application" but you can make the above method do anything you need it to as normal.

As a side-note, it's generally a bad idea to do a lot of work in a type initializer like this.

EDIT: You can store code as a string, use [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile it at execution time, and then execute the compiled code. I have a sample of this in ["Snippy"](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) which I used for C# in Depth as a quick tool for compiling snippets.

Comment: So there's no way changing Constant to Non-Constant during Run-Time ?

Comment: @Cody: If you can initialize it to the right value to start with, why would you *want* to?

Comment: @Jon Skeet im just curious if i can achieve that ,so please tell me if that's possible or not !

Comment: Let me clear ,i need to Inject code during Runtime token from a String ,so can i store C# Syntax into a String declared and Inject it during RunTime ?

Answer (score 0):

It is theoratically possible. See

> How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

You can write the code in a string and compile using the API mentioned in above article.

I have not done that before but it should give you an idea on how to start.

Also see,

[Can I change value of constant in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174453/can-i-change-value-of-constant-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

It may not even exist at runtime, the compiler could have just replaced all usages of it with their literal values (in fact, it probably has, though I don't think it's required to by the standard).

So no, I don't see how this could be possible.